# MySQL Как при создании триггера использовать столбцы с двух таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

При создании триггера должны использоваться два столбца из разных таблиц. Имеются две таблицы - заказы(p_orders) и издательство(p_publications). Суть триггера - когда количество заказанных копий(ordered_copies) превышает кол-во книг(count_of_books), должно ставиться максимальное кол-во книг, имеющихся у издательства.

```
create trigger ordcopies_notmore_count
before insert 
on p_orders
for each row
if  new.ordered_copies > count_of_books then
set new.ordered_copies = count_of_books;
end if;
```

Вопрос в том как сослаться на столбец из другой таблицы в этой части?

```
if  new.ordered_copies > count_of_books then
    set new.ordered_copies = count_of_books;
```

Comment: *как сослаться на столбец из другой таблицы в этой части?* Ну это просто - обычный SELECT. Вопрос в том, из какой именно записи нужно брать значение для сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется делать отдельный запрос в `p_publications`, который вернет `count_of_books`. А уже после эту переменную использовать в триггере.

Как-то так:

```mysql
    create trigger ordcopies_notmore_count
    before insert 
    on p_orders
    for each row
        SELECT COUNT(book_id) INTO @countOfBooks FROM p_publications WHERE ... ;
        if  new.ordered_copies > @countOfBooks then
            set new.ordered_copies = @countOfBooks;
        end if;
```

Вопрос не совсем полный. Подразумеваю, что `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ... WHERE`  Вам нужно будет подработать, чтобы считать книги только определенного издательства...
Но это уже Вы сами. Или добавьте больше информации по структуре Ваших таблиц.

Comment: А зачем эти промежуточные переменные и куча лишних телодвижений, когда всё прекрасно собирается в одно выражение? `SET new.ordered_copies = LEAST(new.ordered_copies, (SELECT ...))`.

Comment: "Или добавьте больше информации по структуре Ваших таблиц." что именно нужно добавить?